# strong independence of simple representations over algebraically closed field

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I'm taking a class on topics in algebra. One of the topics touched representation theory, which I've never studied. In particular, the lecturer formulated the following theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $\mathbb F$ be an algebraically closed field and $G$ a group. For every $1\leq i\leq k$ let $\rho_i:G\to \mathrm{GL}(V_i)$ be an irreducible (simple) representation of dimension $n_i$ and let $c_i\in \mathrm{M}_{n_i}(\mathbb F)$. Assume $\rho_1,\dots ,\rho_k$ are pairwise non-isomorphic representations. If $\sum_{i=1}^k\operatorname{tr}(\rho_i(g)c_i)=0$ for all $g\in G$ then $c_i\equiv 0$.

1. Is there a nice (categorical?) way to restate this theorem?
2. Where can I find a nice structural proof?

The appearance of the trace here is a mystery to me.

In fact, where can I read about representation theory from a fairly categorical approach? I feel that several miracles have happened throughout the course and I would like to find them and understand them.

Comment: Here's a useful fact about the trace that may demystify this theorem: If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, the trace pairing $(A,B) = tr(AB)$ is nondegenerate and allows us to identify $End(V)$ with its dual.  In particular any linear map from $End(V)$ to $\mathbb{F}$ can be expressed uniquely as $X \to tr(XB)$ for some $B \in End(V)$. (and of course $End(V)$ is just $n \times n$ matrices if $V$ is $n$-dimensional and we fix a basis)